# Вывести число строкой Intl

Tags: php, yii2, laravel

```
$text= (new \MessageFormatter('ru-RU', '{n, spellout}'))->format(['n' => '11.101']); 
//выведет: одиннадцать целых сто одна тысячная 

$text= (new \MessageFormatter('ru-RU', '{n, spellout}'))->format(['n' => '11.100']);
//выведет: одиннадцать целых одна десятая
```

Как сделать так, чтобы выводило  одиннадцать целых сто тысячных?

Comment: Может математику подучить, где вы видели число 11.100(одинадцать целых, сто тысячных)? или с строкой работать.  К стати вопрос очень интересный где вы видели такое число?

Comment: не понял что значит со строкой работать? Проценты до тысячных просят текстом выводить, хотя там только десятые всегда.

Comment: в принципе придумал вариант, руками вырезать десятые и подставлять тысячные, но это изврат конечно

Comment: Дело в том что в природе не существует числа 11.100, по этому тут только работать с "числом" как со строкой.

Comment: понадобилось в договоре в микрофинансах, говорят по закону так нужно

Comment: ну так и пишите 11.1 это 11 рублей 100 копеек. А вообще увольтесь с такой работы, репутация дороже.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решил проблему так, может быть кому-нибудь пригодиться

```
    $percents_year = "40.4";

    $number = sprintf('%.3f', $percents_year);

        $res = explode('.', floatval($number));
        $num = $res[0];
        $dec = isset($res[1]) ? $res[1] : 0;

        $res = explode('.',$number);
        $decStr = isset($res[1]) ? $res[1] : 0;

        if (floatval($dec) < 100) {

            $first = (new \MessageFormatter('ru-RU', '{n, spellout}'))->format(['n' => $num]);
            $secont = (new \MessageFormatter('ru-RU', '{n, spellout}'))->format(['n' => $decStr]);
            $resText = $first . ' целых ' . $secont . ' тысячных';

        } else {
            $resText = (new \MessageFormatter('ru-RU', '{n, spellout}'))->format(['n' => $number]);
        }

    $percents_year_text = $resText;
```

Answer (score -1):

Во первых такие числа есть и в математике тоже - и называется это точность числа до тысячных.
Я могу вам предложить следующий вариант решения

1. Наследовать класс MessageFormatter
2. Использовать Полиморфизм подкласса вот так

   class MyMessageFormatter extends MessageFormatter{
      public function format($arr){
         //переписать под свою логику
      }
   }

   $text= (new \MyMessageFormatter('ru-RU', '{n, spellout}'))->format(['n' => '11.100']);

Comment: Если бы еще можно было посмотреть где-нибудь исходный код метода format то вообще было бы замечательно

Comment: ну что ж это просто. Например в Notepad ++ есть поиск в файлах Ctrl+Shift+f для этого вам необходимо скачать файлы себе на комп и запустить поиск в этих файлах например public function format

Comment: intl установлена как библиотека php , поэтому логики метода я не вижу

Comment: Ссылку на статью где это доказывается, или в школу снова.